# Upload attachment to Outlook as relative path

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have code that creates a PDF of a sheet and saves it to a relative path. I'm then trying to upload that PDF to an email that displays (not sends). I want this all to happen at once as I click a button (I've assigned a macro to run both macros to this button).

However, I'm having trouble getting the attachment to work. Is it possible to save the attachment as a relative path? I'm doing it this way because the code needs to be standardized so I can use it on quite a few spreadsheets just by copying and pasting.

The specific code I'm using for the email is below.

```
On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail 'Todos dados do email
        .to = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "" & CompanyName & " - Invoice - " & Data & ""
        .Body = "Dear ," & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Please, find enclosed the invoices regarding the (COLOQUE ACORDO AQUI) between our companies."
        .Attachments.Add        'Adicionar Attachments
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Display   '.Display para mostrar o email
    End With
```

Comment: What do you mean by a relative path? Perhaps you can put the code for "creates a PDF of a sheet and saves it to a relative path" in the question.

Comment: Looks like the OP created a new question and got an answer there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098611/excel-vba-attachment-not-working

Answer (score 0):

This is how Microsoft recommends it be done.

```
Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 

 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
 myAttachments.Add "C:\Test.doc", _ 
 olByValue, 1, "Test" 
 myItem.Display
```

See here: [Attachments.Add Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553%28v=office.15%29.aspx)